# Time zone update in php ahead by 11 hours

Tags: php

I'm new here and don't have knowledge in PHP. anyway, i have a wesbite which display sport matches live scores data updated automatically from a XML feed provider. The problem is, at 12 AM the "Today's matches" should be updated, but instead it will update at 11 PM. in another way, it displays yesterday's matches till 11 PM for the next day and i want to be updated 11 hours before it's current update time. This is the code:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include('header.php');
    $flagged1 = 0;
    $flagged2 = 0;
    if (isset($_GET["date"]) and $_GET["date"] != "")
    {
        $dtShow = $_GET["date"];
        if ($dtShow == "tomorrow")
        {
            $yest = date("y-m-d", time() + (60 * 60 * 48));
            $time = date("y-m-d", time() + (60 * 60 * 24));
        }
        else if ($dtShow == "yest")
        {
            $yest = date("y-m-d", time());
            $time = date("y-m-d", time() - (60 * 60 * 24));
        }
        else
        {
            $yest = $_GET["date"]." 00:00:00";
            $newDate = strtotime($yest);
            $yest = date('y-m-d', $newDate);
            $time = date("y-m-d", $newDate - (60 * 60 * 24));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $yest = date("y-m-d", time() + (60 * 60 * 24));
        $time = date("y-m-d", time());
    }
?>
```

Note: To be more specific, the site is hosted by Dreamhost (USA time) and the local time for me is UTC +3.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Enforce timezone of your needs if server configuration mismatches (in general it's good habit to always enforce settings you need to avoid problems when server settings change). Functions like [date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and [date_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php) is probably all you need.

BTW: "USA time"? there's no such thing.